# Is Websocket messge oriented?

Tags: websocket

I am checking out the behaviors of Websocket.
Is Websocket message oriented unlike TCP stream?

For example, when I send data ABC, DEF, GHI, then is it guaranteed to receive data ABC, DEF, GHI? In TCP stream, it is not guranteed: we may receive AB, DEFG, HI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is message-oriented (well, actually frame-oriented).

Per [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455):

> After a successful handshake, **clients and servers transfer data back
> and forth in conceptual units referred to in this specification as
> "messages".  On the wire, a message is composed of one or more
> frames**.  The WebSocket message does not necessarily correspond to a
> particular network layer framing, as a fragmented message may be
> coalesced or split by an intermediary.
>
> ...
>
> The WebSocket Protocol is designed on the principle that there should
> be minimal framing (**the only framing that exists is to make the
> protocol frame-based instead of stream-based** and to support a
> distinction between Unicode text and binary frames).  It is expected
> that metadata would be layered on top of WebSocket by the application
> layer, in the same way that metadata is layered on top of TCP by the
> application layer (e.g., HTTP).
>
> Conceptually, WebSocket is really just a layer on top of TCP that
> does the following:
>
> - adds a web origin-based security model for browsers
> - adds an addressing and protocol naming mechanism to support
>   multiple services on one port and multiple host names on one IP
>   address
> - **layers a framing mechanism on top of TCP** to get back to the IP
>   packet mechanism that TCP is built on, but without length limits
> - includes an additional closing handshake in-band that is designed
>   to work in the presence of proxies and other intermediaries

Comment: "to get back to the IP packet mechanism that TCP is built on" But we get more than just no length limits: We also get guaranteed and in-order arrival, which we don't have with IP either, no?

Comment: @masterxilo: That is provided by TCP, not by WebSocket.